# Define the limit of the integral

Tags: calculus

Solving limits have never been my strongest suit.

Define the limit $$\lim_{b\to ∞} \int_{0}^b xe^{-x}dx$$

Comment: First calculate the integral, using integration by parts.

Comment: Note that in the limit the integral is [$\Gamma(2)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 2):

$$\int xe^{-x}dx=-xe^{-x}-\int -e^{-x}dx=-e^{-x}(x+1)+C$$

$$\int_0^b xe^{-x}dx=1-(b+1)e^{-b}$$

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}(1-(b+1)e^{-b})=1-\lim_{b\to\infty}(b+1)e^{-b}=1-0=1$$

> $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b xe^{-x}dx=1$$

---

Using Gamma Function we have
$$\Gamma(t)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$$

> $$\Gamma(2)=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}dx=(2-1)!=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(e^{-x})'=-e^{-x}$ which implies that $$e^{-x}=-(e^{-x})'$$ Thus $$\int_{0}^{b}xe^{-x}dx=-\int_{0}^{b}x(e^{-x})'dx$$ which can be solved by integration by parts. Making the calculations, you should obtain that $$\int_{0}^{b}xe^{-x}dx=-\frac{b}{e^b}+1-\frac{1}{e^b}=1-\frac{b+1}{e^b}$$ Now take the limit of $b \to \infty$ to conclude that $$\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_{0}^{b}xe^{-x}dx=\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{b+1}{e^b}\right)=1$$ since by L'Hopitals rule $$\frac{b+1}{e^b}\to 0$$ as $b \to \infty$.

---

Note that this limit is the expected value of a random variable that is exponentially distributed with parameter $λ=1$.